# Visual Studio Code - Scaffolding Newly Created File

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I have a gulp file that watches for any source files I add to my project. When it sees that a file was added and the newly created file is empty, I scaffold that file with some boilerplate code.

**The only problem is when I create this file in my editor I have to refresh my editor (Visual Studio Code in this case) in order to see what I just wrote to that file.** (Right now the file just appears blank).

Perhaps there is some way to delay Code displaying the file? Or perhaps there is a faster way to write the file so Code displays it correctly initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin Pasero on the VSCode team sent me this:

- Close VS Code
- Open C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.3.2\resources\app\server\lib\watcher\ base.win32.watcher.js
- Find the following lines:

else if (currentChangeType === watcher.ChangeTypes.CREATED && newChangeType === watcher.ChangeTypes.CHANGED) {
}

- Remove them or comment them out by adding “//” to their beginning of the line
- Restart VS Code

This fix he said would be included in the next update of VSCode.